# Insert whitespace before every capitalize letters in quotes using regular expressions

Tags: regex

here is my problem.
I have thousands lines like followed to convert.
Can I solve it with regular expression?

Original:

```
beSendToTheSpecialCustomer = new BooleanElement("SendToTheSpecialCustomer",false);
```

to:

```
beSendToTheSpecialCustomer = new BooleanElement("Send To The Special Customer",false);
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Edited:**
I just found a not-perfect solution to this in np++

find:

```
(\".*)([a-z])([A-Z])(.*\")
```

replace with:

```
\1\2 \3\4
```

then click "replace all", but that just replace one word in every line each time, so I need click several times to replace all words, but I can finish my job in 1 minute.

**Better solution from Placido**
find:

```
([a-z])([A-Z])(?=[^()]+,(?:false|true)\);)
```

replace with:

```
\1 \2
```

Comment: Which tool? or Which language?

Comment: notepad++.Btw.thanks for editing

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I can only replace it which contains certain number of words,e.g. finding \"([A-Z])(\w+)\" replaced with \" \1\2\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it with Np++ only. But this can be easily done with callback using almost any programming language. For example with PHP:

```
$txt = 'beSendToTheSpecialCustomer = new BooleanElement("Send To The Special Customer",false);';
echo preg_replace_callback('/new\s+\w+\s*\(\s*"(\w+)"\s*,\s*\w+\s*\)/', 
    function($match){
        return preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', '\1 \2', $match[1]);
    },
    $txt
);
```

---

Edit:

Here is a non-perfect solution using regular expressions in Notepad++:

Find

```
([a-z])([A-Z])(?=[^()]+,(?:false|true)\);)
```

Replace with

```
\1 \2
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have not tried your code, but it seems good. And I just found a not-perfect solution in notepad++.

Comment: @Brettyin, I've added another solution using Np++ (also non-perfect).